# Update a node belonging to any user in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am very new to firebase. I have some nodes inside of the firebase database that are separated by user's UID's. Is it possible to find a user's uid to then update a node under said user's key?
For example get the uid for example@email.com then update the access value in settings for that user to false? How could I do this?

```
{  
"users":{  
    "EXuTWDl95MYPxY":{  
        "email":"example@email.com",
        "name":"user",
        "uid":"EXuTWDl95MYPxY"
    }
},
"settings":{  
    "EXuTWDl95MYPxY":{  
        "access":true
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can be done with pretty much any modern language.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to find a user's uid to then update a node under said user's key?

There is no client-side API in Firebase to look up another user's UID by their email address, since that would expose sensitive data.

But you could build something yourself on top of Firebase, for example to allow looking up a user's UID by email address in the database. With your current DB structure that would be something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref("users").orderByChild("email").equalTo("example@email.com")
```

But note that this requires that users have complete read access to `/users`, which means they can also read the other data of each user.

---

Since you mention `node.js` in your tags: there is an Admin SDK for Firebase that runs on Node.js. This SDK runs in a privileged mode that gives is access to all data in your Firebase project. This means it should only be run in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions for Firebase.

With the Admin SDK, you can look up the UID for a user with:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
```

For a complete example, see the [documentation on looking up user info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data).